# How to loop through a String in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an string like this below:

```
{'SAM (manager)','MICHAEL (assi)','BEN(Servent)'}
```

How can I loop through this structure to get the result like this in Javascript

```
SAM (manager)
MICHAEL (assi) 
BEN (servent)
```

My python script to get data

```
for each in rows:
client = each[0] + ' (' + each[1] + ')'
codes.append(client.replace('\t',''))

codes = str(set(codes))
return codes
```

Comment: Not valid in js.

Comment: Please post a valid data structure so that we can help you.

Comment: Your data structure either has to be an array (use square brackets [ and ] instead) or an object with key/value pairs.

Comment: @Bergi that's the problem. This is the exact data structure I have

Comment: Where does that come from?

Comment: I have a python script which get's me this data

Comment: @samscoot So it's a string, not a data structure?

Comment: @samscoot You should fix your python script to return a JSON text

Comment: @Bergi ah right

Comment: The only valid thing that this could be is array of strings.

Comment: I have posted my python script which returns me the string above

Comment: @samscoot Don't use `str()` but rather [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps). That should get you something to work with easily in the JavaScript